# Как получить данные из словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Допустим, у меня есть словарь:

```
slovar = {"1": "2", "3": "4", "5":" 6"}
```

Мне нужно получить данные из списка. На моем примере это `"1"`,`"3"` и `"5"`.
Как мне получить эти данные?

Допустим slovar.keys(), вычесть dict_keys([, еще получить значение внутри кавычек, но это сложно...

А если у меня огромный словарь? Т.е. там все числа до 7 триллионов. `"1"`,`"3"`, `"5"`, `"7"`, `"9"` и так до 7 триллионов.
Это будет обрабатываться ООООЧЕНЬ медленно. Как это сделать легче?

Comment: Приведите пример вашего кода. Если нужно получить только ключи, то не понятно зачем что-то еще вычитать.

Comment: интересно на каком суперкомпьютере в память помещается словарь с __7-ю триллионами__ ключей и значений???

Comment: @MaxU это пример

Comment: @insolor А как же запятые? Они не должны попасть в код. И пробелы тоже.

Comment: @TheNick-Ник я не понимаю вашей проблемы. `slovar.keys()` возвращает набор ключей, в нем нет ни запятых, ни пробелов, ни даже текста dict_keys. Запятые и пробелы вы видите при выводе этого набора через print, но это только текстовое представление.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши данные в словаре:

```
my_dict = {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6'}
```

все ключи:

```
my_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['1', '3', '5'])
```

все значения:

```
my_dict.values()
dict_values(['2', '4', '6'])
```

все пары ключ-значение:

```
my_dict.items()
dict_items([('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6')])
```

PS "А как же запятые? Они не должны попасть в код. И пробелы тоже":
запятых в выводе не будет ;)

```
for k in my_dict.keys():
    print(k)
  
1
3
5
```

они (как и "dict_items()") - часть формата вывода:

```
>>> my_dict.items().__repr__()
"dict_items([('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6')])"
>>> my_dict.items().__str__()
"dict_items([('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6')])"
```

Получение значения по ключу:

```
>>> my_dict['3']
'4'
```

имеет сложность О(1), т.е. очень быстро даже при "до 7 триллионов" записей.